# Django user model. 1 admin account, 1 customer account with the same email and different password

Tags: django, django-users

Im trying to handle a use case where i have 2 roles. (admin , customer)

There will be an admin portal and a customer portal (2 different login pages ).

- An admin can invite a customer
- An admin can be a customer as well , can invite himself into the customer portal
- An admin account must not share the same password as the customer account.
- Email is used as the unique field for both admin and customer account.

For example :

Admin account
 - customer@email.com /password1 
 - List item

Customer account
- customer@email.com /password2

Solution 1:
 - Permission. Having 1 account with admin permission and customer permission. 
(This cant work to fit the bussiness use case)

Based on this article: 
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

Solution 2:
 - Creating 2 django projects. One for each user model since both accounts cant share password. The reason for separating into 2 projects is because resources such as session,login, logout will not be shared. So each portal(admin,customer) has their own  resource.

- A create Customer API to allow admin to create a customer account in customer django project.
- A shared db to share related data

This is the only way i can think of to handle the use case. Please let me know if anyone has a better idea to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the username field to the email first, if you want the user to log in via email, otherwise remember that the username is how the user logs in. Next, create a profiles app. In this app, create a profile model that will have an OneToOne relation with the Django user model (You can call the profile model via. user.profile). In this profile model, you can create a Boolean Field that distinguishes between a customer and an admin. This way when the user logs in, you can check there profile and render the appropriate template. Another way you can do this is via the Groups model already built-in, create 2 groups one for admin, and another for the customer, you can have when the customer registers to be set automatically as a customer, and admins only to be created to the Django admin or a separate portal if you choose.